# PLUpload Total Progress

Tags: jquery

I'm using PLUpload which is a great little tool that I have used a lot. My basic question is - how do I get a progress percentage of ALL the files combined. I have used the script below to output the percentage of individual files, but I can't work out how to give a running total for all.

```
UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
    $("#total").html(file.percent);
}
```

The above gives the percentage of each file - counting from 1 to 100. That's simple and used in most of the examples. But...

```
UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
    $("#total").html(up.total.percent);
}
```

I would have thought the above would just give me the total progress of all files but it doesn't, it just counts up to the percentage portion of each file. For example:

File1 counts 1-60

File2 counts 1-20

File3 counts 1-20

Giving the 100 total.

I'm not sure if this behavior is by design. I've Googled it to death and can't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I was being stupid.

`up.total.percent` DOES work for the total of all files as you would expect but ONLY if the upload is successful!

I haden't realised that the upload was failing at each file and therefor re-setting the counter each time.

Hop this helps someone.